# Is there a modern term for a "modulus of integers"?

Tags: number-theory, terminology

I'm just getting under way, working through Hardy & Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* and ran across a familiar word used with a very unfamiliar definition: "modulus", described as "...a system S of numbers such that the sum and difference of any two members of S are themselves members of S."  I read that as "S is closed under addition and subtraction."

I don't have a problem with the concept, it's just the term that beguiles me.  Later, they observe that "The single number 0 forms a modulus (the *null modulus*)."  So, they have a closed addition operation with an identity element, and subtraction implies the existence of an inverse.  This sounds like a group to me, but I'm a retired programmer and not a mathematician.

Does this idea of a "modulus" have any current use--maybe under another name?

Comment: This sounds like an [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory))

Comment: I would say more like a subgroup, although of course for integers it amounts to the same.

Comment: Maybe it stands for a $\Bbb Z$-module (in modern terms we would say that it's being "embedded" in $\Bbb Z$ as a submodule/ideal, but maybe back then abstract algebra wasn't foundational).